# Flex: preventing mx:Tree from expanding nodes when changes are made

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tree, flex3

Whenever I add a node to my tree, through its XML data source, it expands all the closed branches.

The code for adding is pretty straight-forward:

```
AddNode(xmllTree:XMLList, xmlNew:XML):void {
    xmllTree.appendChild(xmlNew);
}
```

And that's it. It does the same thing when I remove nodes.

Yes, I tried handling the `mx.events.TreeEvent.ITEM_OPEN` event, but despite the promises of [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html#event:itemOpen), that event is not thrown under these circumstances >=/

Is there any other way to prevent this, short of going through the whole list, recording all the closed branches, then closing them again? (Which I'm not convinced would work anyway)

Flex 3.5 SDK here.

Comment: Could you post a more complete example demonstrating the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

...actually, it was probably caused by this silly `openItems="{objXML..node}"` member of the `mx:Tree` that the original developers put in. I don't know what they were thinking.